# Collecting input data and showing it in div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have some quantity inputs. I want to collect the data in "inputs" and show them in "#yolcudropdown". But I just can't pull the data. Inputs must be disabled. There should be no manual entry. I did something at the bottom of the "javascript" section. But I couldn't run it.

```js
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.number = function(customOptions) {
        var options = {
            'containerClass' : 'number-style',
            'minus' : 'number-minus',
            'plus' : 'number-plus',
            'containerTag' : 'div',
            'btnTag' : 'span'
        };
        options = $.extend(true, options, customOptions);
        var input = this;
        input.wrap('<' + options.containerTag + ' class="' + options.containerClass + '">');
        var wrapper = input.parent();
        wrapper.prepend('<' + options.btnTag + ' class="' + options.minus + '"></' + options.btnTag + '>');
        var minus = wrapper.find('.' + options.minus);
        wrapper.append('<' + options.btnTag + ' class="' + options.plus + '"></' + options.btnTag + '>');
        var plus = wrapper.find('.' + options.plus);
        var min = input.attr('min');
        var max = input.attr('max');
        if(input.attr('step')){
            var step = +input.attr('step');
        } else {
            var step = 1;
        }
        if(+input.val() <= +min){
            minus.addClass('disabled');
        }
        if(+input.val() >= +max){
            plus.addClass('disabled');
        }
        minus.click(function () {
            var input = $(this).parent().find('input');
            var value = input.val();
            if(+value > +min){
                input.val(+value - step);
                if(+input.val() === +min){
                    input.prev('.' + options.minus).addClass('disabled');
                }
                if(input.next('.' + options.plus).hasClass('disabled')){
                    input.next('.' + options.plus).removeClass('disabled')
                }
            } else if(!min){
                input.val(+value - step);
            }
        });
        plus.click(function () {
            var input = $(this).parent().find('input');
            var value = input.val();
            if(+value < +max){
                input.val(+value + step);
                if(+input.val() === +max){
                    input.next('.' + options.plus).addClass('disabled');
                }
                if(input.prev('.' + options.minus).hasClass('disabled')){
                    input.prev('.' + options.minus).removeClass('disabled')
                }
            } else if(!max){
                input.val(+value + step);
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$('.quntity-input').each(function () {
  $(this).number();
});




/* THIS IS IMPORTANT */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '.btw', function() {
    $('#yolcudropdown').text($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```css
.number-style {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-pack: start !important;
  justify-content: flex-start !important;
  -ms-flex-align: center !important;
  align-items: center !important;
}
.number-style .number-minus,
.number-style .number-plus {
  height: 28px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid #e2e2e2 !important;
  width: 28px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -ms-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  line-height: 23px;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: Center;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.number-style .number-minus:active,
.number-style .number-plus:active {
  background: #e2e2e2;
}
.number-style .number-minus {
  line-height: 20px;
}
.number-style .number-minus::after {
  content: "-";
  font-size: 10px;
}
.number-style .number-plus {
  line-height: 18px;
}
.number-style .number-plus::after {
  content: "+";
  font-size: 10px;
}
.number-style .quntity-input {
  width: 28px;
  background: #e00f23;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -ms-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  line-height: 21px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: Center;
  margin: 0 5px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  height: 28px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="quntity-input btw" type="text" value="0" step="1" min="0" max="10">
<input class="quntity-input btw" type="text" value="0" step="1" min="0" max="10">

<div id="yolcudropdown">İnput quantity show this div</div>
```

"class" names of "input" elements are the same. I need to collect inputs with the same value and display them in the div instantly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### HTMLInputElement

Input [**type** `"text"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) has no `min` `max` or `step` attributes, so your HTML is absolutely **invalid**. Try not to write *It-works, I'm a framework* -code. Respect the W3C standards. 
Use `type="number"` (CSS pseudos can help you remove default *spinner* arrows from such elements)

Also `step` *could* be floats. Respect that and use `parseFloat()` in JS

#### CSS Flex to align stuff

Seems you know about CSS-flex, use it! Height, therefore- line-height... 19? 20? 23px? No. Just *use flex*.

#### CSS !important

`!important` is sign of poor coding style and should be left to [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/) only. Or to hopefully override Bootstrap styles - or in that cases when developers actually know what they are doing.

#### jQuery Plugins

[**jQuery plugins**](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/), I suggest to read the DOCS and get a deeper knowledge on how plugins work. Almost every jQuery method *is* a plugin. `.hide()` , `.addClass()`... I won't count them all. Plugins are **chainable** `.removeClass("foo").stop().fadeTo(1)`, and so should be your `.number()` plugin.
To achieve chain-ability you simply **return** the bound `this`.  PS: that's not jQuery... that's how JS works.

jQuery Plugins are not meant to be called inside a `$.each()` loop. `$()` is already a **collection** of DOM Nodes wrapped in a jQuery Object. No need to `.each()`. Same like: you would rather use `$('a').css({color:'blue'})` instead of `$('a').each(){ $(this).css({color: 'blue'}); });`. Same effect, less code. Plugins.

#### jQuery DOM ready

```js
jQuery(function($) { }); // DOM ready and $ alias in scope
```

Or if you don't care about ±IE, or you use ES6 syntax and a toolchain like Babel than: `jQuery($ => { })` will suffice.

#### jQuery $ Object Constructor

[jQuery allows you to define an HTMLElement](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#creating-new-elements) that will eventually become a new DOM element wrapped with all the jQuery powers, Methods. Meaning that, if instead of passing a selector, you pass a more complex Tag-alike string (say: `$("<span/>", {});` - jQuery will create an *inMemory* SPAN element and allow you to use the second parameter `{}` for most of the available [jQuery Methods](https://api.jquery.com/) for that *$Element*. Let's use this!

#### jQuery plugin callbacks

If you want to provide a *callback* after a user changes the input value, provide a **callback method**. Don't force a programmer to write new *spaghetti* code, stick to the scope of your available Plugin internal Methods.

## Sum Elements values

To sum Elements values you can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), just make sure to use an *`initialValue`* to prevent possible TypeErrors.

---

### Example

Finally, here's the simplified CSS and improved JS:

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.number = function(customOptions) {

    const options = $.extend(true, {
      containerTag: "div",
      containerClass: "number-style",
      minusClass: "number-minus", // consistency in wording!
      minusText: "-", // Give power to the user!
      plusClass: "number-plus",
      plusText: "+",
      btnTag: "button",
      onChange() {}, // Provide a nifty callback!
    }, customOptions);

    this.each(function() { // Use .each() here!

      const $input = $(this);
      let val = parseFloat($input.value || 0); // floats! 
      const min = parseFloat($input.attr("min"));
      const max = parseFloat($input.attr("max"));
      const step = parseFloat($input.is("[step]") ? $input.attr("step") : 1);

      const handleStyles = () => {
        $minus.toggleClass('disabled', val <= min);
        $plus.toggleClass('disabled', val >= max);
      };
      
      const change = () => {
        val = Math.max(min, Math.min(max, val)); // Keep val in range.
        $input.val(val); // Update input value
        handleStyles();  // Update styles
        options.onChange.call($input[0], val); // Trigger a public callback
      }

      const decrement = () => {
        val -= step;
        change();
      };

      const increment = () => {
        val += step;
        change();
      };

      const $minus = $(`<${options.btnTag}>`, {
        type: "button",
        title: "Decrement",
        class: options.minusClass,
        text: options.minusText,
        on: {
          click: decrement
        }
      });

      const $plus = $(`<${options.btnTag}>`, {
        class: options.plusClass,
        title: "Increment",
        text: options.plusText,
        on: {
          click: increment
        }
      });

      const $wrapper = $(`<${options.containerTag}>`, {
        class: options.containerClass,
      });

      $input.after($wrapper);
      $wrapper.append($minus, $input.detach(), $plus); // Append all
      handleStyles(); // handle initial styles

    });

    return this; // make your plugin chainable!

  };
})(jQuery);



jQuery(function($) { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

  const $quantityInp = $('.quantity-input'); // Cache your elements!
  const $dropdown = $('#yolcudropdown'); // Cache your elements!

  $quantityInp.number({
    onChange(val) { // our custom onChange callback!
      const tot = $quantityInp.get().reduce((acc, el) => {
        acc += parseFloat(el.value);
        return acc;
      }, 0);
      $dropdown.text(tot);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
/* QuickReset */ * { margin:0; box-sizing:border-box; }

.number-style input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
.number-style input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.number-style {
  display: flex;
}

.number-style > * {
  height: 2em;
  min-width: 2em;
  border-radius: 2em;
  display: flex;            /* Use flex. */
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0;
  background: #ddd;
}

.number-style button {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  /* no highlight, please! */
}

.number-style button:active {
  background: #0bf;
}

.number-style input {
  background: #e00f23;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.number-style .disabled {
  opacity: 0.2;
  cursor: default;
}


/* Custom overrides: */

.number-style>* {
  width: 2em;
  /* just for roundness */
}
```

```html
<input class="quantity-input" type="number" value="0" step="1" min="0" max="10">
<input class="quantity-input" type="number" value="0" step="1" min="0" max="10">

<div id="yolcudropdown">0</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Additional reading:

- [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)
- [Math/min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)
- [Math/max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)
- [jQuery plugin-creation](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation)
- [$ new-elements](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#creating-new-elements)
- [Array/reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [jQuery.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

<sup>And PS: it's *"quantity"*, not *"quntity"*</sup>

Comment: Impressive, but surely write-only for OP.